# Having issues with this basic while loop HW problem

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So I am assigned to print the lyrics for the song below. Although my code does print correctly the class I am completing at Udacity will not accept it. Any ideas what the issue can be? Thank you so much for your help. I have included the instructions as well as my code and output to the console below. Again thank you.

```js
var num = 99;

while ( /* your stop condition goes here */ num >= 1) {

  // check value of num
  newNum = num - 1;

  // print lyrics using num
  if (num === 2) {
    console.log(num + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around ... " + newNum + " bottle of juice on the wall!")
  } else if (num === 1) {
    console.log(num + " bottle of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottle of juice! Take one down, pass it around ... " + newNum + " bottles of juice on the wall!")
  } else {
    console.log(num + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around ... " + newNum + " bottles of juice on the wall!")
  }
  // don't forget to check pluralization on the last line!
  // decrement num
  num = num - 1;
}
```

Directions:
Write a loop that prints out the following song. Starting at 99, and ending at 1 bottle.

99 bottles of juice on the wall! 99 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 98 bottles of juice on the wall!
98 bottles of juice on the wall! 98 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 97 bottles of juice on the wall!
...
2 bottles of juice on the wall! 2 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 1 bottle of juice on the wall!
1 bottle of juice on the wall! 1 bottle of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 0 bottles of juice on the wall!
Some Notes:

Note the pluralization of the word "bottle" when you go from 2 bottles to 1 bottle.
Your text editor may try to autocorrect your ellipses (...) to the ellipses character (…). Do not use the ellipses character for this quiz; use three consecutive periods instead.

Udacity gives the following messages:

> **What Went Well**
>
> - Your code should have a variable num with a starting value of 99
> - Your code should include a while loop
> - Your while loop should have a stop condition
>
> **What Went Wrong**
>
> - Your while loop is producing incorrect output
>
> **Feedback**
>
> Not everything is correct yet, but you're close!

Comment: 99 bottles of juice on the wall! 99 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 98 bottles of juice on the wall!
98 bottles of juice on the wall! 98 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 97 bottles of juice on the wall!
...
2 bottles of juice on the wall! 2 bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 1 bottle of juice on the wall!
1 bottle of juice on the wall! 1 bottle of juice! Take one down, pass it around... 0 bottles of juice on the wall!

Comment: I don't know how picky it is on the output; could it be because of the space before the ellipses? (`pass it around ...` instead of `pass it around...`)

Comment: @ricky898 it seems you're adding extra space before `...`

Comment: sorry! first time posting on here. will make sure to not add pictures as answers. and omg youre right. i deleted the spaces and my code went through. I really appreciate the help guys. <3

Answer (score -1):

Heres a different version where we use interchangeable variables, this allows us to have one `console.log()`.  I don't see a need to check for more than 2 because the while loop will only execute if `num > 1`

```js
var num = 99
var bottle1 = 'bottles'
var bottle2 = 'bottles'

while (num >= 1) {

  if (num === 2) {
    bottle1 = 'bottles'
    bottle2 = 'bottle'
  }

  if (num === 1) {
    bottle1 = 'bottle'
    bottle2 = 'bottles'
  }

  console.log(`${num} ${bottle1} of juice on the wall!, ${num} ${bottle1} of juice! Take one down, pass it around... ${num - 1} ${bottle2} of juice on the wall!`)

    --num
}
```

Comment: While this is improved code, it doesn't actually answer the question, which was why the (seemingly) correct code wasn't being accepted by Udacity. It turned out that there was a typo in the string which caused Udacity to say the output wasn't valid.

Comment: That code looks much more efficient as well. Thanks for the help again and the new way for solving this problem.